# Is there any way to get transpose of selected columns only in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a large dataset where I have about more than 350 columns and I want to convert those 350 columns into rows and rows values as columns. The users provide the ranking "1-10" to brands and I want to show ranking (1-10) as columns.

Here is how my df looks:

```
id          Gender       Age            BMW         Audi         VW         Mercedes
1             M          20              3           1           4            2
2             F          50              1           2           3            4
3             F          25              2           1           4            3
```

And i would like to change it in this way as desired column.

```
id          Gender       Age            Rank1         Rank2           Rank3          Rank4      
1             M          20              Audi        Mercedes          BMW            VW      
2             F          50              BMW          Audi             VW             Mercedes
3             F          25              Audi         BMW              Mercedes       VW
```

In this way I can get rid of so many columns... Any solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far and why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can **`melt+pivot`**:

```
idx = ['id','Gender','Age']
m = df.melt(idx).pivot_table(index=idx,columns='value',values='variable',aggfunc='first')
out = m.add_prefix('Rank').reset_index(idx).rename_axis(index=None,columns=None)
```

---

```
print(out)

   id Gender  Age Rank1     Rank2     Rank3     Rank4
0   1      M   20  Audi  Mercedes       BMW        VW
1   2      F   50   BMW      Audi        VW  Mercedes
2   3      F   25  Audi       BMW  Mercedes        VW
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea that why i have increase in number of rows? Before i had about 22900 rows and now i have 23100

Comment: @s_khan92 hard to tell since we dont have more context on the data , may be try the same with `idx = ['index','id','Gender','Age']` and instead of `df.melt(...` use `df.reset_index().melt(...` , just guessing though

Answer (score 2):

Same idea, however, you cannot reduce the column by using this type transpose

```
df.set_index(['id','Gender','Age']).stack().\
     reset_index(level=-1).set_index(0,append=True)['level_3'].\
        unstack(-1).add_prefix('rank_').reset_index()
0  id Gender  Age rank_1    rank_2    rank_3    rank_4
0   1      M   20   Audi  Mercedes       BMW        VW
1   2      F   50    BMW      Audi        VW  Mercedes
2   3      F   25   Audi       BMW  Mercedes        VW
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it will reduce columns because i have about 350 brand list. I am here just showing only 4 as an example.